# How to tell Visual Studio to use a different source code directory to debug into a library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, class-library

I provided clients with a C++ class library that they use in one of their C++ project.

They want me to investigate when a specific assert happens in the library, and sent me their client code to debug it.

I reproduced the assert on my computer, and was prompted by Visual Studio to specify a directory containing the source code to the library, for debugging.

I selected my development directory, but noticed that when navigating the call stack in Visual Studio, it directed me to wrong places in the source code. I realized this was because the directory I notified contained newer source code for the library (not the source code that was used to build the library that was sent to the client).

Fortunately, I have the source code that was used to build the library that was sent to the client. Unfortunately, I do not know how to tell Visual Studio to use this source code directory instead of the one I erroneously specified before.

How can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the name of the directory...

This should force Visual Studio to ask again for a directory, since it will no longer be able to find the code...

Comment: Or if it's a single file, you can close the file in Visual Studio and then change the name of the file.

Answer (score 4):

Try editing the **Debug Source Files** page.

This property page specifies where the debugger will look for source files when debugging the solution.

To access the **Debug Source Files** property page, right-click on your Solution in **Solution Explorer** and select **Properties** from the shortcut menu. Expand the **Common Properties** folder, and click the **Debug Source Files page**.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdks6de6.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately the directory with the source code of my library was not listed in the **Debug Source Files** page (neither the source code used to build the library for the client, nor the source code of the newest release).

Comment: Try changing the name of the directory... This should force Visual Studio to ask you again for a directory, since it will no longer be able to find the code...

Comment: @bastos-sergio Genius! Why didn't I think about it? It indeed forces Visual Studio to ask again for the directory. Would you mind writing it as a separate answer so that I can set it as accepted (it is a different answer that what you originally suggested that worked after all).